# How to redirect to previous route with data from current route in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a PC build helper website. On homepage there is a list of categories. I click on "Choose" button for a category and it takes me to a page where there are list of products of that category. I select a product by clicking and it should take me to my home page back, and the name of the product should be printed alongside that category.

I am doing this using node js, express, and ejs. My home page has a default "/" route(accessed by typing localhost:3000). When I click choose, it goes to "/product" route(localhost:3000/product), and the name of category is on top of that page. I click on select on a product, it should take me back to homepage on route "/", show the name of product alongside the category.

I am not being able to do this. I cannot pass data from "/product" route by using res.redirect() to my "/" route or homepage. What I did instead, I rendered my homepage onto "/product" route. Thus I am being able to use that data in this route. I wanna be able to redirect to my home route with the data selected from "/product" route and wanna use that data into home route.

I have searched references such as "How to pass data to previous route using express and node js" but didn't find anything helpful for my project.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/productDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

//Database Part Start

const listProcessor = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    core: Number,
    thread: Number
});

const ListProcessor = mongoose.model("ListProcessor", listProcessor);

const item1 = new ListProcessor({
    name: "AMD Ryzen 5 3600",
    core: 6,
    thread: 12,
    price: 17100
});
const item2 = new ListProcessor({
    name: "AMD Ryzen 7 3700x",
    core: 8,
    thread: 12,
    price: 30000
})

const processorArray = [item1, item2];

//Database Part end
//server part and get post part start

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("buildown", {name: "Not Specified", price: "Not Specified"});
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    const signal = req.body.choose;
    if(signal === "cpu")
    {
        ListProcessor.find({}, function(err, items){
            if(items.length === 0)
            {
                ListProcessor.insertMany(processorArray);
                res.redirect("/product");
            }
            else{
                res.redirect("/product");
            }
        });

    }
});

app.get("/product", function(req, res){
    res.render("list", {listTitle: "Processor", listOfProduct: processorArray}); //Using EJS passing data from processorArray
});
app.post("/product", function(req, res){
    const nameItem = req.body.select;
    ListProcessor.find({nameItem}, function(err, items){
        console.log(items);
        res.render("buildown", {name: nameItem, price: items.price});
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Up and Running");
});

//Get Post part end
```

This code first renders homepage to "/" route, with the categories, and Not Specified" text alongside categories. After clicking on choose button, redirects me to "/product" route with a list from data of the mongo DB database I created here. After clicking "Select" it renders the homepage into this "/product" route with the data and product's name in place of "Not Specified" text.

This is all okay but I don't wanna render homepage in this route. Instead this whole action will take place on "/" route. So I would select data from "/products" route, immediately it will redirect to "/" route and I will have the data selected from "/product" route and will use it here.

Can you give me a clue on how to do that? Using just express and node js.

Comment: I suggest you to user request session to store the route history as an array. With this, you just have to redirect to the last -1 saved route.

Comment: Can you explain how it works elaborately? And what do I need to search in google to learn how to do this?

Comment: First install [express session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and configure it. 
After create a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), in it, get the history recods (an array variable you initialize) and push it the req.originalUrl inside it.
Finally, if you wanna redirect to previous, just get your history array and get the before last one (the last is your current url)